# Creating a short shell script to print out a table using cut, sort, and head to arrange values

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need help on this homework. I thought I basically solved it, but two results does not match. I had "psychology" at line 5 where it's supposed to be line 1 and I have "finance" as the last row instead of "Political science". The output (autograder) is attached below for clarity.

Can anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Question is:

- write a short shell script to first download the data set with wget from the included url
- Next, print out "Major,Total" (the column names of interest) to the screen
- Then using cut, sort, and head, print out the n most popular majors (largest Total) in descending order
- You will want to use the -k and -t arguments of sort (on top of ones you should already know) to achieve this.
- The value of n will be passed into the script as a command-line argument

I attached output differences between mine and the autograder below. My code goes like this:

```sh
number=$1

if [ ! -f recent-grads.csv ]; then
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/college-majors/recent-grads.csv
fi

echo Major,Total
cat recent-grads.csv | sed -i | sort -k4 -n -r -t, recent-grads.csv | cut -d ',' -f 3-4 |   head -n ${number}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Don't make us follow links: put the relevant text into the question. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for help formatting your code as code.

Comment: Thank you for being receptive as I'm new here. I fixed the question, however should i keep the pictures as links? I don't think I can embed them yet

Comment: You should add the contents of the task in revised form to the question so it's self-contained, yet minimal, and provide a minimal input file so everybody can reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: Try inverting the order of `sort` arguments. `-k4` put as last. `sort -n -r -t, -k4` Also try doing `LC_ALL=C sort ...` but I don't think it should affect `-n` numeric sort. Why do you do `sed -i`? Remove it.

Comment: No, do not keep the pictures. Simply post some concise, testable **textual** sample input and expected output and describe your problem. Describe what you're trying to write code to do so we don't have to try to figure it out by reading your code. Don't say "one result does not match" - show us which output in the sample you provide doesn't match.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried putting `-k4` as last, but it didn't change the output. I also removed sed -i because you're right, it doesn't matter here.

Comment: `sort -t, -k4nr recent-grads.csv | head -n ${number} | cut -d, -f3,4` outs the exact output shown in your image

Comment: @oguzismail It still shows the same output unfortunately. On my local Rstudios, it works. But for some reason on autograder, the results aren't the same. `echo Major,Total
sort -t, -k4nr recent-grads.csv | head -n ${number} | cut -d, -f3,4` is what I put down

Comment: @Delman : What is the `sed -i` supposed to do? There are no replacement operations being done. Also you can get rid of the `cat`. Finally, you feed stdin into `sort`, but you also provide an explicit file to sort. Do either one or the other. For debugging, have a look at the interim files of each step of your pipe, i.e. `sort SOMETHING INPUTFILE|tee interim.1|cut ...|tee interim.2|head ....`, and then inspect  the interim files.